# Is there any way to reduce the W/WO ratio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-multithreading, termination

For experimentation purposes only, the goal of the following code is run as fast as possible in a cross-platform way that leads to the fewest problems while allowing threads to be stopped in Python. The specific code in question revolves around the `Thread` class that inherits from `threading.Thread` and that allows a thread to be stopped by raising an exception that automatically gets caught once started. The question is fairly simple: **Is it possible to reduce the W/WO ratio reported by the code without changing anything except the implementation of the new `Thread` class provided here?**

When running this, the "with/without threading" ratio is usually around 5.7 (meaning that the new `Thread` class takes about 5.7 times longer to execute the benchmark than would normally be the case). Changing the code for `Test.run` can cause changes in the W/WO ratio, but this is not the part of the code that optimization is to be applied to since it only represents a busy no-operation loop. The goal is to change the implementation of `Thread._bootstrap` so that there is less overhead in what the interpreter must do between each bytecode instruction that the virtual machine must execute.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import functools
import statistics
import sys
import threading
import timeit


LIMIT = 1000000
SAMPLES = 30


def main():
    repeat = functools.partial(
        timeit.repeat,
        setup=f'from __main__ import Test; t = Test({LIMIT})',
        repeat=SAMPLES,
        number=1
    )
    slow = statistics.mean(repeat('t.start(); t.join()'))
    fast = statistics.mean(repeat('t.run()'))
    print(f'With thread:    {slow:.3f}')
    print(f'Without thread: {fast:.3f}')
    print(f'W/WO ratio:     {slow / fast:.3f}')


class StopThread(StopIteration):
    pass


threading.SystemExit = SystemExit, StopThread


class Thread(threading.Thread):

    def _bootstrap(self, flag=False):
        if threading._trace_hook:
            raise RuntimeError('cannot run thread with tracing')

        def stop():
            nonlocal flag
            flag = True
        self.stop = stop

        def func(*_):
            if flag:
                raise StopThread()
            return func
        sys.settrace(func)
        super()._bootstrap()


class Test(Thread):

    def __init__(self, limit):
        super().__init__()
        self.limit = limit

    def run(self, count=0):
        while count < self.limit:
            count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```